ADO - REST - Cannot find a way to get pipeline creator id
I need to know the person who created a pipeline in ADO
https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_apis/pipelines/***?api-version=7.1
I get everything but a "createdby" field
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/****/****/_apis/pipelines/****?revision=**"
        },
        "web": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/****/****/_build/definition?definitionId=****"
        }
    },
    "configuration": {
        "path": "azure-pipelines.yml",
        "repository": {
            "id": "*******************",
            "type": "***************"
        },
        "type": "yaml"
    },
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/****/****/_apis/pipelines/****?revision=**",
    "id": ***,
    "revision": **,
    "name": "****",
    "folder": "\\****"
}

how can I achieve this ?
thanks for your help

I am afraid that there is no Rest API can directly get the creator info of the Pipeline.  But we can confirm who performed the created operation by looking at the first revision of the Pipeline. This method can work for both Classic and YAML Pipeline. You can refer to my answer for more details.

Based on your description, you need to get the user who creates the Pipeline.
To meet your requirement, you can use the Rest API: Definitions - Get Definition Revisions
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/revisions?api-version=7.1

In the Response, you can check the response with revision value 1, where the changed user(changedBy) corresponds to the user who creates the pipeline.
For example:
 "value": [
    {
      "revision": 1,
      "name": "txx",
      "changedDate": "2024-10-15T14:41:59.987Z",
      "changeType": "add",
      "definitionUrl": "xx",
      "changedBy": {
        "displayName": "xxx",
        "url": "xx",
         .....
        "id": "dd61a310-16c1-6ca5-a217-f243df542c22",
        "uniqueName": "xx",
        "imageUrl": "xx",
        "descriptor": "msa.ZGQ2MWEzMTAtMTZjMS03Y2E1LWEyMTctZjI0M2RmNTQyYzIy"
      }
    },
   ]

PowerShell sample:
$token = "PAT"

$BuildDefinitionID = PipelineID

$OrgName= "OrganizationName"

$ProjName= "ProjectName"

$GetBuilddefinitionurl="https://dev.azure.com/$($OrgName)/$($ProjName)/_apis/build/definitions/$($BuildDefinitionID)/revisions?api-version=7.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$GetBuildRevisions= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetBuilddefinitionurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json


foreach($revision in $GetBuildRevisions.value)
{

   if($revision.revision -eq "1")
   {
      $PipelineCreatorID = $revision.changedBy.id

      $PipelineCreatorName= $revision.changedBy.uniqueName

      echo "Creator ID: $PipelineCreatorID ; Creator Name: $PipelineCreatorName"
   }

}


thanks I'll have a go with that, yet confirming the user is the right one, might take some time with my colleagues, so I validate your answer as is
